# Add ability to see who edited or answered question in android application

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Whenever an edit is made or a question is answered, the post is bumped up. However there is no way to see who edited or answered the post.

The answerer (is that a word?!?) can be found out by viewing the post, but in case of edits only on opening the question on browser can we see who edited.

I request that the name of the user who answers or edits a post be displayed along with “edited x minutes ago”

Comment: I support this. It's confusing when Community user bumps unanswered questions, making me wonder "What was modified?"

Comment: I guess it would be a tough job(Developmentwise) to bring in all the features of SE to a limited environment. Much of what can be ported to mobile has been done. May be the development team is trying hard to accomodate as much as features as possible.