# Differentiating between the question editor or answerer in the Android app

Tags: support, design, android-app

I am new to Stack Exchange and I just wanted to thank the person who answered my question, but I am confused. Is the name (in the red-marked region) written below an answer the person who edited the answer or the person who originally answered the question?

> [image: Red marked region names person who edited the answer or the person who originally answered the question?]

Comment: I don't use the mobile app but looking at it with a web browser yes is was user213305 that answered the question - although if you're happy with the answer rather than posting a thanks comment (which isn't recommended) you could consider accepting the answer which will give them +15 rep to thank them.

Comment: What version of the app? In the iOS version, whether a username appears in the "edited" section depends on whether the edit was done by the OP or not. If it was, there's no name. If the editor was someone else, like how Jamal has edited your question here, it shows the username and icon of the editor. If you're using the Android App... which might be the case as that doesn't look like the iOS app... I can't confirm whether that's the case but the edit your're talking about in your image *was* done by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of the SE Android app (1.0.95) doesn't show the name of the user who made an edit of the post (there is only the name of the original post author). This sometimes this confuses me, i.e. it is not possible to detect who updates the post.

If you really want to know you need to go to web site (full or even mobile), or use Apple device and iOS SE app, which has a field with a name of editor, like in web.

Here is the difference for your current post:

In the app:

> [image]

In the mobile web:

> [image]

Also there is [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248588/339911) to add an information about the name of the post editor to the Android app.